# Spring Boot log4j2 application creates one empty and one working log file

Tags: xml, spring-boot, log4j2

Let's suppose we have a simple Spring-boot app:

pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<!-- other dependencies -->

    </dependencies>
```

log4j2.xml (src/main/resources/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout disableAnsi="false">
                <pattern>%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{3.}}{bright,yellow}: %highlight{[%p] %msg%n%throwable}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="c:/tmp/sw-b2b-data-service/logs/sw-b2b-data-service.log"
                     filePattern="c:/tmp/sw-b2b-data-service/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/sw-b2b-data-service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{3.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                        size="4 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

I'm using Windows, so *log4j2.xml* contains lines like "file...=c:/tmp/...".

I use a relative path for log file location usually, but this time I've decided to move log files out of the project folder to a temporary dir.
And now when I deploy the jar it contains *log4j2.xml* with those "file...=c:/tmp/..." lines in "BOOT-INF/classes".

I thought there'll be no problems with that config, cause we always override the default *log4j2.xml* using *-Dlogging.config=./log4j.xml* in the service's start line.

But now every time I start the service it creates a folder structure of "c:/tmp/.../logs/" in the service's working folder with an empty *sw-b2b-data-service.log* file inside.

Actual logs are going to the log file defined in the overriding *log4j2.xml* (something like *%service's_root%/logs/sw-b2b-data-service.log*).

[image]

How can I get rid of that folders (and empty file inside) creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Spring Boot starts Log4j is configured twice:

- as soon as some `LogManager.getLogger` is called, Log4j performs automatic configuration (cf. [Log4j documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration)),
- when Spring has initialized its environment, it configures Log4j again programmatically (see [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.custom-log-configuration)).

In your case `log4j2.xml` is used to configure Log4j the first time (and creates the first file), whereas the value of the Spring property `logging.config` is taken into account only during the second configuration.

To change this behavior your should:

- rename `log4j2.xml` to `log4j2-spring.xml` so that the file is not used during the first configuration (it will be used by Spring if you don't specify `logging.config`),
- or, alternatively, set the system property `log4j2.configurationFile` to the location of the new configuration. This setting will work after the first configuration, but will be overridden as soon as Spring reconfigures the context.